# CoreData to CloudKit migration

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

What is the best way to migrate from CoreData to CloudKit and keep all user's data?

I would like to retire Core-Data and replace it with CloudKit but users have tons of important data and it should be migrated somehow.
Also lots of classes are working with CoreData entities and they shouldn't be affected (except CRUD operations).
Didn't find any straightforward guidelines for that.

My draft solution:

-check if user has CoreData

-load all CoreData objects in memory

-write them to cloud

-remove CoreData file

Is it something that will work as expected?

It is okay to use classes inherited from NSManagedObject after Core-Data removal?
Could it cause any side-effects?

Comment: Keep in mind that CloudKit data is not available for offline use. It's only available if you have a network connection.

Comment: Thank you! yes it's a problem.... looks like CloudKit is very early stage but I wouldn't like to use third-party tools like Firebase etc. So the best solution for now is to synchronize CoreData with CloudKit?

Comment: Yes CloudKit (cloud storage) and CoreData (local storage) serve very different purposes, might help to CloudKit Basics. You would have to build your own logic to map the CoreData Entities to CloudKit Record Types. You do have the facility to archive the Record's metadata (like change tags). Refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH1-SW1 for basics. Then watch WWDC videos.

Comment: Thank you for reference. I've found the project https://github.com/mentrena/SyncKit and it does the job. It works like expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So CoreData can't be replaced by CloudKit because CloudKit doesn't support offline mode. 
I've found library to synchronize my CoreData with CloudKit and it works like expected.
Library: https://github.com/mentrena/SyncKit

UPDATE: got multiple issues with SyncKit even before release and finally migrated to Firebase. Works fine in prod.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone finding this since WWDC19, CloudKit CoreData sync is now offered by Apple.

The core step to use this technology is to switch from `NSPersistentContainer` to `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`

There are some additional steps you can take to allow background syncing.

Full details can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit

I have also found this article to be an excellent reference:

https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/blog/ios-development/data-persistence/getting-started-with-nspersistentcloudkitcontainer/